How to pass a ZOD schema to a client component so i can dynamically set validation for an input field
I have recently created a input field client component for a POC that needed some inbuilt validation. I initially hard coded this as we just wanted to show that the ui does change based on if the input does meet certain criteria. Since then im trying to add a prop whereby i can pass a validation schema to test against, meaning that wherever we created an input field we can individually assign it validation, so for example, we could differentiate between say a password input field and a username input field. Unfortunately i get the below error:
 error Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server".

my types
import { ZodSchema } from 'zod';

export type InputFieldProps = {
  label: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  placeholder?: string;
  icon?: React.ReactNode;
  statusErrorMessage?: string;
  statusSuccessMessage?: string;
  width?: string;
  validation?: ZodSchema;
};


as you can see, i have a statusErrorMessage which would be replaced by what i set in the zod schema, and the successMessage id probably just have as a 'meets all validation' or something for now. On my page I have tested the normal zod stuff and its all working fine but i just want a way to dynamically pass it to a component so we can create schemas and pass it through at the page level for quick development. Does anyone know a way to achieve this? please let me know if you need more context and thank you for reading

Have tried passing the schema itself
json stringifying an object version of the schema (which seems to work but unsure how to return it to the schema on the otherside as parse gives me jibberish)
the schema on the page works fine but obviously its not hooked up to anything


The only other way i can think to do this is to have a file with schemas, import this into the client component and then pick one based on a switch statement but yeah would rather avoid that if i can

ive gone with this so im going to close this question but yeah, thanks

The answer was to just create a zod library of schemas, pass in a value that it can use as a switch statement to return the correct one

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
